# OnItemCLickLIstener doesn't work on ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have an activity with a ListView. ListView with custom views. I add OnItemClickLIstener to the ListView. and when i click on item, in result i see nothing.
Activity with ListView:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/silver_conv">
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/topcontainer"
        android:background="@color/black">
</FrameLayout>
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/chat_list" android:layout_below="@+id/topcontainer"
        android:layout_above="@+id/last_action"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp" android:clickable="true"/>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="last action was at time" android:id="@+id/last_action"
          android:longClickable="false"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="false" android:layout_above="@+id/action_container"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="43dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/action_container"
        android:background="@drawable/conv_botom_action_gradient">
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/send"
            android:id="@+id/send_message_btn" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button_selector" android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/add_attach_btn"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/add_attach_button_selector"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp" android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="40dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/message_et"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/add_attach_btn" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_message_btn"
              android:singleLine="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:hint="Type message here"
              android:background="@drawable/message_input" android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
              android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

View item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_vertical|left" android:focusable="false">

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/incoming_message"
        android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:focusable="false">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:id="@+id/attach_container" android:focusable="false"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="saa"
            android:id="@+id/message_text" android:textSize="17sp" android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:focusable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/date" android:textColor="@color/black" android:singleLine="true" android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1" android:ellipsize="none" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:focusable="false"/>
```

And finally clickListener:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener clickLister = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
        try {
            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.container);
            TextView message = (TextView)container.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            message.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            Log.e("My item is", "" + pos);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

And here is Initialization of ListView:

```
mConvListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.chat_list);
    mConvListView.setDivider(null);
    mConvListView.setDividerHeight(0);
mConvListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    mConvListView.setOnItemClickListener(clickLister);
    mConvListView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    mConvListView.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

P.s. Sorry for a lot code. But I can't find any suggestion a second day.

Comment: why `AdapterView.onItemClickListener` not `ListView...`. Did you try just `mConvListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting focusable objects in your row layout, you are preventing the ListView from getting the touch event.

This FrameLayout is consuming the touch event:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/attach_container" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

Remove the focusable settings so it looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/attach_container" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

(You really should organize your XML so that is is readable, in Eclipse use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.)

Answer (score 3):

Make Focus for all components as follows :

```
   android:focusable="false"

   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not getting the item the right way. Try this:

```
int position = (int) adapterView.getSelectedItemId();
Log.i("Position:", Integer.toString(position));
```

**Edit**

Try this piece of code.

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.chat_list);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) { 

             int position = (int) parent.getSelectedItemId();
             Log.i("Position:", Integer.toString(position));
       }
});
```